# Can not assign observable data to local variable in angular

Tags: angular, http, get

**My Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient,HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  isAdmin;
  getLogIn(email:string,password:string):Observable<boolean>{
    let params = new HttpParams().set("userEmail",email).set("userPassword", password);
    return this.http.get<boolean>("http://localhost:8080/user/login",{params: params});
     }
}
```

**My Subscribe call**

```
 email:string="";
  password:string="";
  adminFlag:boolean=false;

  login(event: any) {
    console.log(this.adminFlag);
    this.userService.getLogIn(this.email,this.password).subscribe(data => this.adminFlag=(data));
    console.log(this.adminFlag);
    if(this.adminFlag){
      console.log("INSIDE IF")
        this.router.navigate("../../home");
    }
  }
```

When i log in data var in console I am getting raw data as

```
true
```

but i couldn't assign it to this boolean "adminFlag" it is changed to undefined

Anything I missed...???

the API is returning a boolean..I need that boolean to be assigned...

Comment: Where have you checked that the response is a boolean? In the service? Also, you should have the adminFlag checks inside the subscribe. Is this just a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTTP GET](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) is an [asynchronous request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921). Which means you are reading the variable `adminFlag` before it is being set. Move the routing inside callback to set the value and use it. Its also always good practice to include error callback in HTTP requests. This should work:

```
login(event: any) {
  this.userService.getLogIn(this.email,this.password).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.adminFlag = data; 
      if (data) {
        this.router.navigate("../../home");
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.error('getLogIn failed');
      // handle error...
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing:

```
    this.userService.getLogIn(this.email,this.password).subscribe(data => this.adminFlag=(data));
```

it means that you expect DATA to be a boolean. It's an observable boolean instead. 
To get the real boolean, use the pipe function, eg:

```
getLogIn(email:string,password:string):boolean{
  let params = new HttpParams().set("userEmail",email).set("userPassword", password);
  return this.http
    .get<boolean>("http://localhost:8080/user/login",{params: params})
    .pipe(map(data => data);
}
```